# how can a BPEL variable be put into a shell variable

Tags: shell, unix, bpel, xmlstarlet, xmllint

a BPEL process creates a xml document, a certain XSD file that has xml structure and i want to parse that BPEL variable with xmllint or xmlstarlet with a unix shell commandline command. is that possible at all?

how can i put the BPEL variable into a shell variable , in order to be able to parse it with xmllint for instance?

#### INPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns:ItemList xmlns:ns="http:///blabla">
    <GenericItem>
        <ns2:LocalItem xmlns:ns2="http:///blabla">
            <ItemSource> </ItemSource>
            <ConcItemSource>
                <name></name>
                <requirements/>
                <strategy/>
            </ConcItemSource>
            <dataFormat/>
            <directory></directory>
            <file/>
        </ns2:LocalItem>
    </GenericItem>
    <GenericItem>
        <ns2:LocalItem xmlns:ns2="http:///blabla">
            <ItemSource>
            </ItemSource>
            <ConcItemSource>
                <name></name>
                <requirements/>
                <strategy/>
            </ConcItemSource>
            <dataFormat/>
            <directory></directory>
            <file/>
        </ns2:LocalItem>
    </GenericItem>
</ns:ItemList>
```

Comment: POST your sample XML

Comment: <ns:ItemList xmlns:ns="http:///blabla">
      <GenericItem>
       <ns2:LocalItem xmlns:ns2="http:///blabla">
    <ItemSource> </ItemSource>
    <ConcItemSource>
 <name></name>
 <requirements/>
 <strategy/>
    </ConcItemSource>
   <dataFormat/>
   <directory></directory>
   <file/>
  </ns2:LocalItem>
 </GenericItem>
...
</ns:ItemList>

Comment: What do you want to fetch inside ?

Comment: i want to fetch directory for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) :

```
$ cat bpel.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns:ItemList xmlns:ns="http:///blabla">
    <GenericItem>
        <ns2:LocalItem xmlns:ns2="http:///blabla">
            <ItemSource> </ItemSource>
            <ConcItemSource>
                <name></name>
                <requirements/>
                <strategy/>
            </ConcItemSource>
            <dataFormat/>
            <directory>d1</directory>
            <file/>
        </ns2:LocalItem>
    </GenericItem> 
    <GenericItem>
        <ns2:LocalItem xmlns:ns2="http:///blabla">
            <ItemSource>
            </ItemSource>
            <ConcItemSource>
                <name></name>
                <requirements/>
                <strategy/>
            </ConcItemSource>
            <dataFormat/>
            <directory>d2</directory>
            <file/>
        </ns2:LocalItem>
    </GenericItem>
</ns:ItemList>
```

#### command line :

```
$ dir1=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//directory[1]/text()' bpel.xml)
$ echo "$dir1"
d1
```

#### Using a for loop :

```
$ count=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(//directory)' bpel.xml)
$ for ((i=1; i<=count; i++)) {
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//directory[$i]/text()" bpel.xml >> newfile
}
```

But you can do simply :

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//directory/text()" bpel.xml >> newfile
```

#### xmlstarlet from `STDIN` :

```
command_producing_xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//directory/text()" -
```

Comment: thanks, so you pull the whole xml into a file on the drive first right?      would it be possible to do a for loop with xmlstarlet to run through the directories and then for instance write all directory names into a text file?

Comment: so bpel.xml is a shell variable, that does not physically exist right?

Comment: It's a  file... You can use STDIN if you prefer.

Comment: STDIN would work how_? sorry but i am quite a beginner, i just want to minimize the access to the drive from my workflow, that is why i want to put that xml in a variable without having to use a physical file

Comment: so i could basically ECHO the xml content and then read that from STDIN right_?

Comment: i have put the xml into a shell variable xmlstring and now i do :   count=$(echo $xmlstring | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(//directory)" -) && for ((i=1; i<=count; i++)) {echo $xmlstring | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/directory[$i]/text()" - >> /opt/XMLTEST/xmltest.txt} and it get error: syntax error near unexpected token `{echo'

Comment: Missing `;` before the ending `}`

Comment: that does not do it,  does the for loop not have to be something like: FOR....DO ....DONE ?

Comment: It's a another way, yes. : `for ((;;)); do ...; done` Do you try by yourself ? POST a new question if you have a problem. Thanks to clean this thread with useless informations (in the comments). Code should never provided in a comment (do you see how it's not well formated ?).